# How to Enable Scrolling in a Flutter ListView.separated Inside a YoutubePlayerScaffold

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, screen-orientation, flutter-renderflex-error

I have a Flutter app with a YoutubePlayerScaffold containing a ListView.separated. I want to enable scrolling in the ListView.separated while avoiding renderflex errors when exiting fullscreen mode in the YouTube player. How can I achieve this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_iframe/youtube_player_iframe.dart';

class PlyrOneScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  PlyrOneScreen({Key? key, required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: YoutubePlayerScaffold(
        builder: (context, player) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Column(
              //mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                player,
                ListView.separated(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text(
                      'data $index',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Divider(
                      height: 3,
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 100,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        controller: YoutubePlayerController.fromVideoId(
          videoId: 'Nen3UXaWDDE',
          params: const YoutubePlayerParams(
            showFullscreenButton: true,
            
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm facing an issue with my Flutter app's layout. I have a YoutubePlayerScaffold containing a ListView.separated widget inside a Column. When I wrap the ListView.separated with an Expanded widget to enable scrolling, I can scroll the list, but I encounter a renderflex error when exiting full screen mode (changing screen orientation from landscape to portrait). On the other hand, when I add a SingleChildScrollView around the Column and remove the Expanded widget, the renderflex error on exit full screen is resolved, but I can no longer scroll the list. I'm looking for a solution that allows scrolling in the ListView.separated without encountering renderflex errors on exit full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your error-less & warning-less code. I made some enhancements to the code. Feel free to try & test it out. I made the YouTube player pinned & listview scrollable. If you want something else, then leave a comment down below.

Source code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:youtube_player_iframe/youtube_player_iframe.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "My App",
      theme: ThemeData(colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue, useMaterial3: true),
      home: const PlayerScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class PlayerScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlayerScreen({super.key});

  static String videoId = "ggG9ySCChYw";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation) {
          return orientation == Orientation.portrait
              ? SafeArea(bottom: false, child: mainWidget())
              : mainWidget();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget mainWidget() {
    return YoutubePlayerScaffold(
      controller: YoutubePlayerController.fromVideoId(
        videoId: videoId,
        params: const YoutubePlayerParams(showFullscreenButton: true),
        autoPlay: true,
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget player) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: player,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.star),
                    title: Text("Title: $index"),
                    subtitle: Text("Subtitle: $index"),
                    trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                    onTap: () {},
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return const Divider(height: 1, thickness: 1);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! its worked...Thanks for your valuable answer

Comment: YouTube player Fullscreen is not working as expected, when trigger full screen sometimes it logs as full screen but not change in screen, help me please!

Comment: It's an open issue in GitHub: https://github.com/sarbagyastha/youtube_player_flutter/issues/241